# gpg: public key decryption failed: Operation cancelledgpg: decryption failed: No secret keystatus: Int = 2

Tags: encryption

When I was using below command I was getting above mentioned issue.

example : gpg  --passphrase  "xyz"  -d -o test.csv test.txt.pgp"

Answer (score 0):

We need to add --batch-yes in before the decrypt the command.

example : gpg --batch --yes --passphrase "xyz" -d -o test.csv test.txt.pgp"

Comment: You should accept you own answer if it solves the question :)